# How does Python interpreter look for types?

Tags: python

If I write something like:

```
>>> a = float()
```

how does Python interpreter know where to look for type 'float'?

I know that 'float' is a variable defined in Lib/types.py and refers to built-in type `types.FloatType`. But how does the interpreter build a complete list of all possible types for a script (including user-defined and imported-module-defined)? Which places does it look in? And what do I do to build such a list inside a Python script?

Comment: try: `dir(__builtins__)`, `help(__builtins__)`

Comment: Yeah, that's not it :) I need a complete list, and these functions just return what's been defined inside current module. So I can have what's inside mine + inside __builtins__, but those would not be all. If i, say, import module some_module with a class SomeClass defined inside, it would not appear on the list, while using it as some_module.SomeClass would not be a problem. And I want to get everything that interpreter would.

Comment: What do you mean, a complete list? Of what? What are you using the list for?

Comment: You can use `globals()` to get a list of all global variables, and `locals()` to get a list of all local variables... I have no idea what you're trying to do, but my suspicion is that you're trying to solve a different problem in a very awkward way ... Perhaps you should give more details are what you're *really* trying to do.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I need a complete list of all types (and oldstyle-classes) that can be used in a module. I'm writing a decorator that checks types of arguments of function. So I need a list of all types there can be.

Comment: @Gleb: there is *no limit* to the types a Python program can produce though. I am free to produce as many types as I damn well like, dynamically, at runtime. You cannot ever find them all because any code can produce more types.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean "all there can be". I meant "all that are defined at the moment of decorated function call". And if a type is defined dynamically, it will still appear in globals as a TypeType or ClassType variable.

Comment: @Gleb: but you cannot know what the function call will do. It can produce new types too. Functions can define new types with a nested `class` definition or call to `type()` and these would not live in the module globals.

Comment: A dynamically created type needs only one reference to exist; it could be the only reference is from a value of that type, and it does not need to have a name at all, let alone a global one.

Comment: So if I want all types that are accessible at some point of runtime, I need to: 1) unwrap the nested functions from execution point, while looking for locals() 2) look in module globals() 3) look in builtins. Correct?

Comment: @Gleb: unwrapping functions is not going to do it; each time the sample function in my answer is called, it creates a **new** type. Given the same arguments it doesn't re-use a class object, the new object is entirely new. If you call it a 100 times, you'd have 100 distinct classes. They'd all implement the same functionality but are distinct nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, you wrote "how does the interpreter build a complete list of all possible types" - but this contains a false assumption. There is no complete list of possible types. There is an effective set of existing types, but they are not arranged in a list.

You have a namespace, which typically looks in a certain order: function (locals), module (globals), builtins. In parsing code the compiler also selects type constructors for [literals](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals). Every name at each place could refer to any object, among which a lot are types:

```
>>> [name for name in dir(__builtins__) 
     if isinstance(getattr(__builtins__,name), type)]
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 
 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'DeprecationWarning', 'EOFError', 
 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'FloatingPointError', 'FutureWarning', 
 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 
 'IndexError', 'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 
 'NameError', 'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 
 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'ReferenceError', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 
 'StandardError', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 
 'SystemExit', 'TabError', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 
 'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 
 'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'ZeroDivisionError', 'basestring', 
 'bool', 'buffer', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'classmethod', 'complex', 'dict', 
 'enumerate', 'file', 'float', 'frozenset', 'int', 'list', 'long', 'memoryview', 
 'object', 'property', 'reversed', 'set', 'slice', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'super', 
 'tuple', 'type', 'unicode', 'xrange']
```

The interpreter isn't actually interested in how many types there are, only how they each apply to interpreting the code to be run. It finds that by using the type pointer, which every object has:

```
>>> type(1)
<type 'int'>
```

The result is that if two types don't fit, it's their job to tell you:

```
>>> 1+"foo"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
>>> "foo"+1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
>>>
```

The first `+` is actually `int.__add__`, and the second is `str.__add__`, simply looked up via the object on the left. (It gets a little more complex with alternate attempts like [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__), but the basic principle is the same.)

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be, "How is this a type declaration?"  The answer is, it isn't a type declaration.  Names in Python have no type associated with them.  Names refer to values, and values have a type, determined at runtime.

When Python executes `a = float()`, it looks up the name `float`, and finds it in the builtins, it's a function.  It calls that function with no arguments.  The return value is a float object.  The name `a` is then made to refer to that object.  That's all it does.  Before it's executed this line of code, Python has no idea what `a` will become, and it has no idea that floats will be involved.

Python is dynamic, so your line of code could have been in this program:

```
def float():
    return "I'm not a float!"

a = float()
```

Now when `a = float()` is executed, the builtin has nothing to do with it, and there are no floats anywhere, and `a` refers to a string.

For more on names and values, see [Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 1):

If a name is to be resolved as a global, and there is no matching global (you don't have a function named `float` in your module), then Python looks at the `__builtins__` object that is part of the global namespace for every module.

That object is a built-in module, defined in C. See [`Python/bltinmodule.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0b79c702abda/Python/bltinmodule.c).

In the case of `float`, the name is bound to the C `PyFloat_Type` structure, in a [series of assignments](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0b79c702abda/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2694), and the `PyFloat_Type` structure is defined in [`Objects/floatobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0b79c702abda/Objects/floatobject.c)

Fundamentally, Python doesn't have 'type declarations'; `float` and `str`, etc., are just C structures that conform to certain behaviour; they produce values that Python can recognize as a certain type when queried. Thus, anything produced by `float()` points back to `float` as its type.

And because `__builtins__` is only consulted when you don't have a global by the same name already, you can easily provide your *own* implementation of the `float()` callable; one that returns something entirely different when called.

If you wanted to enumerate all built-in type objects, loop over the builtins and enumerate anything that is an instance of `type()`:

```
import __builtin__

for name, obj in vars(__builtin__).iteritems():
    if isinstance(obj, type) and not issubclass(obj, BaseException):
        print name, obj
```

How `__builtins__` works is an implementation detail of the CPython implementation, but the same objects are exposed as the [`__builtin__` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) used here.

Note that you cannot ever hope to gather all possible types code can produce. Functions can produce new types that are local to the function, and are *not* listed in the module globals; types do not need to be listed there to work:

```
def dynamic_types(name, base=object):
    class DynamicType(base):
        def __repr__(self):
            '<{} (DynamicType) at {:#x}>'.format(self.__name__, id(self))
    DynamicType.__name__ = name
    return DynamicType()
```

The above function produces objects with a *new* type (Python classes are types too) each time you call it. You'll not find that type in the module globals, nor in the builtins.

Comment: Ok. And after that? If the name is not in builtins, I mean. Does it look in imported modules recursively? And if it's not there, throws an exception? Or goes to look somewhere else?

Comment: @Gleb: what are you building? It sounds like you're trying to implement a Python interpreter! :)

Comment: @Gleb: imported modules are globals. If a name is not in your globals nor in `__builtins__` then a `NameError` is raised.